# pass self.kwindow var to imported function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, kendo-ui, export

I am moving my `doIt` function to another separate file, as it's gotten so large.

After doing so my `self.kwindow` is becoming *undefined* in the new file `./doIt.js`.

I tried passing as a param, *i.e.* below but nothing. How is this done?

### **./big.js**

```
    import { doIt } from './doIt.js';

    // lots of other JavaScript functions

    self.kwindow = initWindow();

    setTimeout(() => { 
      doIt (self.kwindow); <-- recent attempt as param
    }, 90);

    // previously doIt function was here self.kwindow worked in this scope
```

---

### **./doIt.js** *(now in new separate file)*

```
    function doIt () { 
      // lots of stuff, many references to self.kwindow
      // self.kwindow no longer recognized in this scope
    }

    export {
       doIt,
     };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If helpful to anyone; I got it working by broadening the scope via below. Then passed `wkindo` in both `doit(wkindo)` instances.

```
setTimeout(() => { 
  var wkindo = self.kwindow;
  doIt(wkindo);
}, 90);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass a parameter, just call an instance of the window via jQuery in that .js:

```
function doIt () { 
   var kwindow = $("$window").getKendoWindow();
}
```

Comment: But I have many kendoWindows I don't just want to declare and reference a random generic one? it needs to keep the thread of same kendowindow in ./big.js scope..